# When using the multiprocessing library, how do I bind resources to specific processes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, pathos

Say I have 50 processes, and I'm using them to operate on (say) 20000 different input values.  (I'm using the pathos library, which I think operates similarly to the multiprocessing library in Python.)

```
thread_pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool(threads=50)
thread_pool.map(function, inputs)
```

I want to create one SQLAlchemy database engine for each process (but I don't have the resources to create one for each input value).  Then I want all inputs that are processed using that process to work with the same database engine.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could batch your input and map each batch to each thread, open a connection, and then have an iterator in each thread that calls the function on each individual thread using the same connection.

Comment: Is pathos a requirement of yours? The Python standard `mutiprocessing.Pool` allows to do so easily. I looked at pathos implementation (could not find the Pool documentation) and it seems it's not 1:1 with the standard one.

Comment: @noxdafox Yeah I figured out how to do it using the "multiprocess" library (you can use initializers) and moved away from pathos.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah the idea was that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of both `pathos` and `multiprocess`. It turns out that `multiprocess` is actually what `pathos` is using, but maybe it's not obvious that is the case.  You can do it from `pathos`:

```
>>> import pathos
>>> pathos.pools._ProcessPool 
<class 'multiprocess.pool.Pool'>
```

The above is the raw `Pool` directly from `multiprocess`, while `pathos.pools.ProcessPool` is a higher-level wrapper with some additional features, but does not (yet) expose all the keyword arguments from the lower-level `Pool`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this by using the `multiprocess` library instead of the `pathos` library.  When creating a pool of processes, you can specify an "initializer function", which runs at the beginning of each process.  In this initializer function I created a database engine and declared that engine as global to the process.  So now I have exactly one engine per process.